# Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/javawriter/JavaWriter$Scope; while trying to compile with Dagger and dagger-compiler

Tags: java, android, dagger, butterknife

I have these in my applications modules build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

When I try to build i get the exception above ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwmzo.png )

If i don't include the compiler i get:

```
Module adapter for class ....AndroidModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

Why am i getting this exception and how should resolve it?

I am using Android Studio.

Comment: for the record: before i was messing with dagger butterknife worked.

Answer (score 4):

changing

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

to

```
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

solved the problem.